# Labelling footnotes with stanza and line number in reledmac

Tags: eledmac, reledmac

I'm trying to evaluate the feasibility of moving an older project which I had begun still using `ledmac` to `reledmac`. One crucial requirement is the labelling of footnotes with stanza and line number, for which in the `ledmac` package there was the example A.7, Irish verse, `ledbraonain.tex` which I had just slightly adapted to my needs.

As was to be expected, my file didn't compile anymore after just changing to `\usepackage{ledmac}`, and it looks as if the modifications necessary are not trivial. Also, skimming the `reledmac` documentation, I didn't find any example which does what I want.

In the following a rather simplified, but surely not minimal file, my real project features two commentaries to the verses, and four registers of apparatus.

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{reledmac}
\usepackage{amssymb}%For Sigma and friends.

\newcommand{\sn}{SN757}

\newcounter{stanzanum}
\setcounter{stanzanum}{4}
%\newlength{\stanzaindentbase} Obviously already defined.
\setlength{\stanzaindentbase}{20pt} %Play with it later.
\setstanzaindents{4,1,2,1,2,3,3,1,2,1}


%%% Want to label the footnotes with the stanza and line number
%%% We'll use \linenum to replace the sub-line number
%%% with the stanza number, redefining \edtext to do this
%%% automatically for us.
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%\makeatletter
%
%\renewcommand{\edtext}[2]{\leavevmode
%  \begingroup
%    \no@expands
%    \xdef\@tag{#1}%
%    \set@line
%    \global\insert@count=0
%    \ignorespaces \linenum{||\the\c@stanzanum}#2\relax
%    \flag@start
%  \endgroup
%  #1%
%  \ifx\end@lemmas\empty \else
%    \gl@p\end@lemmas\to\x@lemma
%    \x@lemma
%    \global\let\x@lemma=\relax
%  \fi
%  \flag@end}
%
%%% We need only a very simple macro for footnote numbers,
%%% to produce the stanza number (sub-line) then the line number.
%\def\printstanzalines#1|#2|#3|#4|#5|#6|#7|{\begingroup
%%  #3\fullstop \linenumrep{#2} % Got rid of the full stop
%#3\linenumrep{#2}
%  \endgroup}
%\let\oldprintlines\printlines
%
%\makeatother



\begin{document}

\beginnumbering
\linenumberstyle{alph}
{\large 
\stanza 

kim akāṇḍa eva jagatāṃ \edtext{viparyayād}{\Bfootnote{$\Sigma$; viparyād \sn}} &
iva śūnyatām \edtext{upagatāḥ}{\Bfootnote{E$_{DR}$\sn D$_{BC^{pc}DE}$; upagatā Ś$_C$JD$_{AC^{ac}}$.}} stha śuṣmiṇaḥ | &
kathayanti vo hṛdaya\edtext{śalyaduḥkhitām}{\Bfootnote{E$_D$\sn Ś$_{CD}D_{BCD}$; śalyaduḥkhatām JD$_{AF}$; duḥkhaśalyatām D$_E$ }} &
adhunā mukhacchavaya eva dhūsarāḥ || 5 || \&

}
\endnumbering


\end{document}
```

Comment: After all it does look easy, only one line in the definition of `\edtext` needs to be changed. A first test now looks positive, still testing a bit.

Comment: The aim of o (r)eledmac is to avoid redefining internal command of ledmac. However, for now, there is no tools which correspond to the example ledbraonain.tex.

Comment: I have open a new issue for this https://github.com/maieul/ledmac/issues/373. It should be quite easy to implement it. I will try to do it this afternoon, and will send you a message when I will need test.

Comment: The main part is encoded. I have just to make some little change for parallel typesetting + to add option after the stanza separator. I hope to do it tomorrow night.

Comment: I have posted a tutorial to make test. https://github.com/maieul/ledmac/issues/373#issuecomment-127175165 could do them and report ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The version 2.1.0 of reledmac, now dowloaded at https://github.com/maieul/ledmac/archive/2.1.0-2.2.0.zip and, I hope, send in CTAN next week, provides tools to do what you need.

1. `\numberstanzatrue` enable automatically stanza numbering.
2. `\Xstanza` add this number in notes.
3. `\Xstanzaseparator{.}` changes the separator between stanza number and line number.

Here a MWE

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{reledmac}

\usepackage{amssymb}%For Sigma and friends.

\newcommand{\sn}{SN757}

\setlength{\stanzaindentbase}{20pt} %Play with it later.
\setstanzaindents{4,1,2,1,2,3,3,1,2,1}


\numberstanzatrue
\Xstanza
\Xstanzaseparator{.}
\begin{document}

\beginnumbering
\linenumberstyle{alph}
{\large 
\stanza 
 kim akāṇḍa eva jagatāṃ \edtext{viparyayād}{\Bfootnote{$\Sigma$; viparyād \sn}} &
iva śūnyatām \edtext{upagatāḥ}{\Bfootnote{E$_{DR}$\sn D$_{BC^{pc}DE}$; upagatā Ś$_C$JD$_{AC^{ac}}$.}} stha śuṣmiṇaḥ | &
kathayanti vo hṛdaya\edtext{śalyaduḥkhitām}{\Bfootnote{E$_D$\sn Ś$_{CD}D_{BCD}$; śalyaduḥkhatām JD$_{AF}$; duḥkhaśalyatām D$_E$ }} &
adhunā mukhacchavaya eva dhūsarāḥ || 5 || \&

\stanza 
 kim akāṇḍa eva jagatāṃ \edtext{viparyayād}{\Bfootnote{$\Sigma$; viparyād \sn}} &
iva śūnyatām \edtext{upagatāḥ}{\Bfootnote{E$_{DR}$\sn D$_{BC^{pc}DE}$; upagatā Ś$_C$JD$_{AC^{ac}}$.}} stha śuṣmiṇaḥ | &
kathayanti vo hṛdaya\edtext{śalyaduḥkhitām}{\Bfootnote{E$_D$\sn Ś$_{CD}D_{BCD}$; śalyaduḥkhatām JD$_{AF}$; duḥkhaśalyatām D$_E$ }} &
adhunā mukhacchavaya eva dhūsarāḥ || 5 || \&

}
\endnumbering


\end{document}
```